# Do we have any mechanism to track if app is installed from a given URL?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, firebase-analytics

Example:

Link : www.example.com/bje3x

The link will redirect to playstore or appstore url. So if user installs the app from the playstore, can we know if the app ins installed from the redirection URL above?

Comment: you exactly want that if app is installed by your given particular link or by other link correct? or you just want that app is installed or not?

Comment: I want to check if the app is installed by user clicking some custom link.

Comment: I think you can use your open url function in app delegate to achieve your requirement. but I am not sure that first time if application is installed from custom link then app will call that method or not.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged with `firebase-analytics` so I guess you are comfortable using Firebase. Then one possible solution for you would be to use [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links). They are *designed* for this use case.

In short you define what is your destination URL - kind of deep link - and if app is installed it just works as a deep link. If app is not installed, it can redirect to AppStore and then inside the app at launch you can retrieve your deep link. Of course it's a bit more complex than that, but essentially it allows you to know what brought the user in.

In the simplest form Dynamic Links use domain provided by Firebase (ending with `.page.link`) but you can also configure your own domain. Also you don't always get 100% matching accuracy, but for the most part - it should work.

There are also other solutions like [branch.io](https://branch.io/) etc. If you look for "deferred deep linking", "smart links" or "dynamic links" you will find more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can achieve this by Deep Linking

A deep link is an intent filter system that allows users to directly enter a specific activity in an Android app. However there is an issue about this process. When a user click an URL, it might open a dialog which asks the user to select one of multiple apps handling the given URL.
On the other hand, An Android App Link is a deep link based on your website URL that has been verified to belong to your website. When user clicks that URL, it opens your app.

Please refer this Url

https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd

Comment: Deep linking and app linking just lets us navigate to specific screens in the app directly from some URL in the website or page. I don't thiink it helps in anyway to determine if user has installed the app with some custom link.